How to show that the abstract complexification of a real matrix Lie algebra (vector space) coincides with complex linear combinations?
Consider a real matrix Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} \subseteq M_n(\mathbb{C}$), e.g. $\mathfrak{su}(n), \mathfrak{so}(n-1,1), \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$.
The complexification of a real Lie algebra may be defined as the formal complex linear combinations $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}} = \mathfrak{g}\oplus J\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. it contains the elements $X + JY$ with $J$ the "abstract" imaginary unit ($J^2=1$) and the commutator defined by extending the commutator of $\mathfrak{g}$ by bilinearity on the imaginary unit $J$.
Here I am skipping over the identification of the tensor product $\mathfrak{g} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ with the above definition of complexification.
In the case of real matrix Lie algebras (or vector space, for that matter), one may also speak about the complex subspace, let us call this $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}}^M$, which consists of the complex linear combinations $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}}^M = \text{span}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathfrak{g}) = \{ X + iY | X,Y \in \mathfrak{g}\}$.
According to Hall [Proposition 3.38], assuming that if $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ then $iX\not\in\mathfrak{g}$, there is a natural (Lie algebra/vector space) isomorphism between the abstract complexification $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}}$ and the matrix complexification $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}}^M$.
The map $X+JY\in \mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}} \mapsto X + iY\in \mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}}^M$ is quite clearly (to me) an surjective homorphism (it conserves linear combinations and the commutator). However, I can't seem to prove that is injective, based on the hypothesis that if $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ then $iX\not\in\mathfrak{g}$ (except for the zero vector 0).
Namely, one would need to prove that $X + iY = X' + iY'\in \mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}}^M$ if and only if $X=X'$ and $Y=Y'$.
In the book this is taken for granted but I don't see how this is obvious. Could anyone help? Thanks.
For context, it is clear to me that if $X$ and $i X$ are both in $\mathfrak{g}$, then we could have $X + i(-iX) = 0 + i0$, meaning that the map cannot be injective.

I don't think this has anything to do with Lie algebras, this is just linear algebra.
Let $K\subseteq L$ be a field extension, let $V$ be an $L$-vector space and $W$ be a $K$-subspace of $V$.
We have a natural map $L\otimes_{K} W\to LW\leq V$ corresponding to the bilinear map $(l,w)\mapsto lw$, which is clearly surjective. Take some $\sum_{k=1}^n l_k\otimes w_k$ in the kernel, so that $\sum_{k=1}^n l_kw_k=0$.
If $L=\mathbf C$ and $K=\mathbf R$, then we may assume that each $l_k$ is either $1$ or $i$ (because they form a basis over the reals) and then combine the $w_k$ terms corresponding to $1$ and the terms corresponding to $i$, yielding $\sum_{k=1}^n l_k\otimes w_k=1\otimes w_1'+i\otimes w_2'$. But the fact that this is in the kernel means exactly that $w_1'=-iw_2'$.
Thus, if your condition is satisfied, $w_1'=w_2'=0$, so $\mathbf CW\cong \mathbf C\otimes_{\mathbf R} W$ as desired.
The way you describe the complexification, you are pretty much skipping right to the step where you only have simple tensors of the form $1\otimes w$ or $i\otimes w$, so the only thing to do is to combine the terms.

Even easier: With the notation of the question, since we know linearity, all we have to show is that $X+iY=0 \implies X=Y=0$ for $X,Y\in \mathfrak g$. But the assumption means $-X=iY \in \mathfrak{g} \cap i\mathfrak{g} ={0}$ (not $={}$ as wrongly claimed in OP).

I have fixed hidden and wrong assumptions in the question for future reference. Thanks for the answer (and the comment).
